# Flutter stuck to run the command flutter doctor in windows 11

Tags: flutter, windows-11

I tried to run the command `flutter doctor` in windows 11. Unfortunately, it hangs on and can't even start the executions.
Anyone we have experienced such issues?

I tried to run the command `flutter doctor` in windows PowerShell and also in the command prompt.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run:

```
flutter doctor -v
```

`-v` will display the *verbose* output. Like that you can see what exactly is the problem.